# How to change the module name in a project in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use IntellIj. I have a project created https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services. I decided to change the name of the project and all modules. I change the name of the project without any problem. However, the problem is when changing the module name.

[image]

I want to change the name of the `web` module to the `popcorn-web` name and the same with other modules. However, after confirming `OK` the name change, nothing happens. The name of the module is the same as the old one and does not change to a new one.

How do I change the module name?

Comment: Try File | Project Structure | Modules | <web> and change the name there.

Answer (score 1):

Shift + F6  once you've clicked on the module :)

Answer (score 0):

You have renamed the module but not the directory itself. If you open up that directory in the file explorer you should see a popcorn.web.iml file.

Comment: How to change the name of the directory? As I change manually in the file browser https://zapodaj.net/29657cc28dda1.png.html to GitHub deletes all classes and adds them again, and I do not want to https://zapodaj.net/4480083db6d88.png.html.